# Probability of string not containing an element

Tags: probability

If given a question where you have a string of length six {U8U8U8} where it is made up of $3$ letters from the alphabet ($26$ options) and numbers from $0$-$9$ ($10$ options), what is the probability that the string does not contain the letter $T$ and the number $9$.

My thoughts on this question were that you take the total number of options for the string being : $26^{3} \times 10^{3}$
And then you can just subtract the number of strings that don't have $T$ or $9$ in them so the probability would be:

$$P = \frac{26^{3} \times 10^{3} - (25^3 \times 9^3)}{26^{3} \times 10^{3}}$$

Is this the correct way to attack a question like this? Or have I done this wrong?

Comment: "...what is the probability that the string does not contain the letter $T$ and the number $9$?"  Given that $E_1$ is the event that the string does not contain the letter $T$, and $E_2$ is the event that the string does not contain the number $(9)$, are you asking for the probability that **at least** one of the events $E_1, E_2$ occurs, or are you asking for the probability that **both** of the events $E_1, E_2$ (simultaneously) occur?

Comment: Re my previous comment, your analysis correctly capitalizes on $E_1, E_2$ being independent events.  However, your math actually represents $1$ minus the probability that events $E_1, E_2$  both (simultaneously) occur.  Given your statement of the problem in the problem's first paragraph, whatever your response is to my previous comment, there is an inconsistency here.

Comment: @user2661923 its the probability that both events occur at the same time.

Comment: In that case, $$P = \frac{25^{3} \times 9^{3}}{26^{3} \times 10^{3}}.$$

Comment: Why is the numerator not $(26^3\times 10^3) - (25^3 \times 9^3)$?

Comment: Because you are trying to compute the chances that events $E_1$ and $E_2$ both occur.  The chance that event $E_1$ occurs is $\displaystyle \left(\frac{25}{26}\right)^3$ and the chance that event $E_2$ occurs is $\displaystyle \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^3$.